# AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute "'element_spec'"

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am very new to tensorflow. I ran following code -

```
import tensorflow as tf
d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.random.uniform([3,6]))
d.element_spec
```

And got following error -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-a00819363729> in <module>()
      1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.random.uniform([3,6]))
----> 3 d.element_spec

AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute 'element_spec'
```

I cannot find solution for this error. I just want to print the type of each element component in variable d. What is going wrong here??

I am using tensorflow 2.0.

Comment: I just tested your code and it works for me. Make sure you are using version 2.0.0-rc1.

Comment: OMG i was using 2.0.0-alpha0. I installed version 2.0.0-rc1 and that solved the issue. Thank you so much @jdehesa...